# How to limit the amount of characters returned in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have a value in my query pulling too many characters so when i try to put the report into an Excel i am hitting 32767 characters error for excel, i am using SSRS to generate the report and it must be in excel format so that can't change.  I need to be able to some how set return 32760 characters only to the select

I tried Trim but that didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are saying, `SUBSTR` returns only a portion of some string, so that would be

```
select substr(your_string, 1, 32760)
from ...
```